# Any interesting conditions on a graph with the following properties?

Tags: graph-theory

This is quite a soft question.  I'm looking for any properties that a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices satisfying the following conditions might have:

1. $\chi(G)=n-2$
2. $|E(G)|>(n^2-3n+6)/2$

Clearly, for example, $n$ must be greater than 3, the clique number of $G$ must be less than or equal to $n-2$, and the density of the graph must be greater than: $\displaystyle\frac{n^2-3n+6}{n^2-n}$.

Are there any nice characterizations of such graphs?

Comment: With that many edges, it might be easier to characterize the complement.

Comment: By $\chi(G)$ you mean the chromatic number or the Euler charateristic?

Comment: I mean chromatic number.  Thanks Gerry, interesting idea, will give it some thought.

Comment: I think order is standard and $\chi(G)$ is standard for chromatic number, and Euler characteristic couldn't possibly be n - 2, could it?